# Query Parameter Values Not Updating When Set from Google Map Component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a map component that contains some clickable overlays on the map. Users can click and unclick the overlays on the map to select them and when they do so the app loads some data based on the overlays that are currently selected.

The current structure is as follows:

1. User clicks the map which executes a function passed to the map as a prop, which takes the current value of the neighborhoods and either adds or removes them from the query string.
2. The function executes a history.push()
3. I use a useEffect checking the value of the query param neighborhood and send a request to the backend to fetch the listings if the values have changed.

My issue is that when the user clicks on the map, the function executes but the value pushed to the params is never updated, causing the logic to fail the next time the user clicks on the map.

Relevant Snippets of Code are as follows:

history/param variables:

```
const { region, state, neighborhood, transactiontype } = useParams();
const location = useLocation();
const { pathname, search } = location;
```

Function that is passed down to the child map component:

```
const updateChildComponentHandler = (dataFromChild, addorRemove) => {
    SetLastSetter("map");
    SetNeighborhoodTypeSelected("custom");

// if a new neighborhood is added, just taking the existing string and adding &`neighborhood`
    if (addorRemove === "add") {
      let newGroup = ""
      if (neighborhood !== "any") {
        newGroup = `${neighborhood}&${dataFromChild}`;
        SetMapChangeType("add");
      }

// if no neighborhood was initially selected, just replacing the "any" with the proper neighborhood
      if (neighborhood === "any") {
        SetMapChangeType("add");
        newGroup = `${dataFromChild}`
      }

// pushing the new parameter string
      const newPath = pathname.replace(neighborhood, newGroup);
      history.push(`${newPath}${search}`);

    
    }

// same concept as above, just removing the neighborhood from the string if it is removed from the map
    if (addorRemove === "remove") {
      let newGroup;
      if (neighborhood !== dataFromChild) {
        newGroup = neighborhood.replace(`&${dataFromChild}`, "")
        SetMapChangeType("delete");
      }

      if (neighborhood === dataFromChild) {
        newGroup = "any";
        SetMapChangeType("add");
      }

      if (neighborhood.split("&")[0] === dataFromChild && neighborhood !== dataFromChild) {
        newGroup = neighborhood.replace(`${dataFromChild}&`, "")
        SetMapChangeType("delete");
      }

      const newPath = pathname.replace(neighborhood, newGroup);
      const newerPath = `${newPath}${search}`;
      history.push(newerPath);
      deleteListings(dataFromChild);

      
    }
    SetUpdateMap(true);
  }
```

UseEffect Logic:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const func = async () => {
    let neighborhoodParams;
    if (neighborhood !== "any") {
      neighborhoodParams = neighborhood.replace("%20", " ").split("&")
    }

    if (neighborhood === "any") {
      neighborhoodParams = [];
      neighborhoodParams[0] = "any";
    }

    const neighborhoods = neighborhood.split("%20").join("_");

      SetNeighborhoodParams(neighborhoodParams);
      SetNeighborhoodParamString(neighborhoods);

      if (mapChangeType === "add") {
        if (neighborhoodParams.length > 0) {
          if (!requestMulti) {
            await fetchProperties(transactiontype, neighborhoodParams[neighborhoodParams.length - 1].split(" ").join("_"), filteredRegion, state, filters, "single")
          }
          if (requestMulti) {
            await fetchProperties(transactiontype, neighborhoods, filteredRegion, state, filters, "multi")
            SetRequestMulti(false);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    func();
  }, [neighborhood]);
```

The issue I am experiencing is that when the map initially loads, the neighborhood is set to "any". The first time a user clicks an overlay for a neighborhood, the correct data is sent from the map and the map/data requests update and the URL parameter up top shows the new neighborhood. However, the second time a user clicks, the value of { neighborhood } is not updated and is still set to "any", so the function just replaces the value of { neighborhood } rather than adding it on as per above. I previously coded this with class components and am trying to convert it to hooks, but it seems like there is some dissonance that is causing the map component not to have access to the updated history variable. I am new to react/hooks, and appreciate if anyone could lend some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: So, if I understand it doesn't update the view but when you console.log it does show right?

Comment: The first time the function executes the value of neighborhood is any by default, so the function just replaces the string with the new neighborhood according to that if statement. The problem is that after that happens, the value of the new neighborhood is pushed to the url up top and everything loads correctly, except the next time the function executes when I console log the value of neighborhood it is still set to "any", even though the params up top show something like "Downtown". So im not sure if the param values are not being passed down to the child map component when they update.